# how do I write to firebase outside of a Firestore trigger?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write to firestore from an http post trigger, however my doc.data() keeps coming back as undefined, even though it clearly exists. (see screenshots). I did find somewhere that MIGHT have the answer I'm looking for but they want $50 for the POSSIBILITY fo an answer lol.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({CREDENTIALS});
const db = admin.firestore();
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
        var ref = db.collection('Messages').doc("18438557133");
        ref.get().then((doc: any) => {
          console.log(doc);
          console.log(doc.data());
          console.log(doc.exists);
          response.end()
        });
    })
```

[image: firestore Screenshot]
[image: console]

this is the link i found that might be helpful:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/dialogflow-with-firebase-cloud-functions/
what am I missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to show more detail.  You should include 1) All console logs from an actual execution. 2) How you are invoking the function. 3) The source of data that you are saying MIGHT be helpful to you.  Bear in mind also that HTTP functions should send a response to the client, and this code is not doing that at all, so it will always time out.

Comment: made edits, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is suggesting that the document doesn't actually exist.  Notice that `doc.exists` is false, and the documentation for [doc.data()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#data) says that it will return undefined if the document doesn't exist.

The Firestore SDKs aren't wrong about this sort of thing.  You might be looking at a different document than the one you think you're getting.  Or you might be looking at a different project than the one where the function is deployed.  In any event, you're going to have to take a close look at your deployment to make sure everything is as you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Your screenshot is already showing a list of all document in some collection.  If you have another question, please post it separately, as there is not much we can do to debug this for you.

Comment: You were absolutely right the document reference was incorrect, I just realized you are the guy from the firebase videos! great content helped me out a bunch.